# Как мне реализовать собственные мониторы и семафоры без использования библиотек?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, монитор, семафоры

У меня есть задание запустить несколько потоков, допустим t1 ,t2,t3,t4
t1, t2, t3 могут обращаются к независимым ресурсам, а t4 пытается лезть к ресурсам t1 ,t2 ,t3. Как написать планировщик потоков/алгоритм планирования потоков не используя уже готовые решения?

```
void func1(){
///code working with file1
}

void func2(){
///code working with file2
}

void func3(){
///code working with file3
}

void func4(){
///code working with file1, file2, file3
}

void main(){
    Thread t1 = new Thread(func1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(func2);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(func3);
    Thread t4 = new Thread(func4);
    t1.Start(); t2.Start(); t3.Start(); t4.Start();
}
```

Comment: Зачем? Это учебное задание?

Comment: Да, учебное задание

Comment: Так или иначе, нужно использовать средства языка, позволяющие _безопасно_ выполнять чтение/запись памяти. Это ключевое слово [volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile), класс [Volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.volatile?view=netframework-4.8), класс [Interlocked](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=netframework-4.8), [методы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8#methods) класса Thread: SpinWait, VolatileRead и пр

Comment: Суть в том, что создаёте некоторую переменную и проверяете/изменяете её состояние с помощью безопасных (атомарных) операций в критических местах кода.